# Use of rather than

Tags: grammar, word-usage

When we using ***either or*** we thinking about two object like  ***either do or not, either red or green***.
So I've to ask if we could use *rather than* for list.
Like:  **Which are your favorite fruits?**

Apple

Banana

Orange

Grape

So can I say I like them all ***rather than*** apple and banana?
And if this isn't correct then what we can use?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"I like them all **other than** apples and bananas" would be most common.
"Rather than" is used in front of an infinitive verb to show a contrary choice. Such as: 
"He chose to eat the apple **rather than** eat the grape."